# Android: Find objects with ParseUser object

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have ParseObject subclass called **Note** and it has column `owner`  which is a pointer to the `User` class (ParseUser). I also have a `ownerSignedOut` column on my object class and when only using that as "rule" it works fine.

Adding the `owner` "rule" gives me no results.

---

**Note** has these columns:

- objectId (String)
- owner (Pointer <_User>)
- ownerSignedOut (Pointer <_Installation>)
- title (String)
- createdAt (Date)
- updatedAt (Date)
- ACL (ACL)

---

Trying to only get objects that belong to a specific `owner` or `ownerSignedOut`

```
List<ParseQuery<Note>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<Note>>();

ParseQuery<Note> query1 = ParseQuery.getQuery( Note.class );
query1.whereEqualTo( "owner", ParseUser.getCurrentUser() );
queries.add( query1 );

ParseQuery<Note> query2 = ParseQuery.getQuery( Note.class );
query2.whereEqualTo( "ownerSignedOut", ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation() );
queries.add( query2 );

ParseQuery<Note> query = ParseQuery.or( queries );
query.addDescendingOrder( "updatedAt" );
query.findInBackground( new FindCallback<Note>() {
    // other code
```

---

- Using only **query1** gives me no results
- Using only **query2** gives me the correct results
- Using **query1 & query2** gives me no results

---

**Edit:**
Here you can see the pointers working fine
[image: A picture showing the objects and their pointers]

---

**Edit 2:**
This is how I create the objects:

```
if ( ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null && ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername() != null ) {
    noteItem.put( "owner", ParseUser.getCurrentUser() );
}

noteItem.put( "title", title );
noteItem.put( "ownerSignedOut", ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation() );
noteItem.saveInBackground( new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done( ParseException e ) {
        setResult( 1 );
        finish();
    }
} );
```

---

**Edit:**
My Installation class has `user` column that is a pointer to User class. Can it be a conflict there?

Comment: The fact that query1 doesn't work makes me think that the current user isn't the same user that is saved in the Note class. Can you verify that they are the same?

Comment: Yes they are the same, and if I press the "Epx7PVcmrx" in the owner column i get to the right user in the ``User`` class.

Comment: And the result of ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId(); matches that as well?

Comment: Exactly. It seems to work fine it's just the query that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark here, but have you tried just adding to one query vs. multiple?

```
ParseQuery<Note> query1 = ParseQuery.getQuery( Note.class );
query1.whereEqualTo( "owner", ParseUser.getCurrentUser() );
query1.whereEqualTo( "ownerSignedOut", ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation() );
queries.add(query1);
```

Comment: I will try it in a bit, but isn't that going to replace the first whereEqualTo? I will try though.

Comment: No, it should essentially add to the query.  Meaning, look for this, then this.  Is that what you are looking for or are you trying to query either or?